# In django, what is the optimal way to access data in a OnetoMany relationship to output to template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm working in django and my objective is to output to a template a table consisting of all my customers and a corresponding amount equal to the total amount they have spent.

I have the classes/models `Customers` and `Transactions` with a OneToMany relationship. Every time a customer makes a purchase, the transaction is recorded as is the amount they spent (`tx_amount`). I have the following set a code that works but I believe is not optimal since its running in O(x * y) time, i.e., running a full loop over `Transactions` for every customer.

Q1: What is the optimal way for accomplishing this task?

When I originally tried to get my template to work, instead of using `local_customer`, I was using `setattr(customer[x],"value",tx_amount)` which worked in the django shell but did not work in the template. My workaround was to create a local class which I would use to population my `context` variable.

Q2: When combining data models to output in a template, is it necessary to use some sort of local class like my `local_customer` implementation below or is there a better way?

Pseudo-code below:

models.py:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Transactions(models.Model):
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tx_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2
```

views.py:

```
class Local_Customer:
    name = ""
    total_spent = 0

    def __str__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def customer_view(request):
    
    customer = Customers.objects.all()
    customer_context = [] # list of objects we'll pass to render

    for x in range(len(customer)):
        local_customer = Local_Customer(customer[x].name)
        customer_txs = Transactions.objects.filter(customer__name=customer[x])

        for y in customer_txs:
            local_customer.total_spent += y.tx_amount
        customer_context.append(local_customer)

     context = {'customers' : customer_context}

    html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

template.html:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
    {{customer.name}}
    {{customer.total_spent}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to do this at the database side:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.shortcuts import render

def customer_view(request):
    customers = Customers.objects.annotate(
        total_spent=Sum('transactions__tx_amount')
    )
    context = {'customers' : customers}
    return render(request, load_template, context)
```

This will thus generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT customers.*, SUM(transactions.tx_amount) AS total_spent
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions ON transactions.customers_id = customers.id
```

and thus fetches all data in a single query.

If there are no transactions, `total_spent` will be `None` (`NULL`), not `0`, you can use [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to use zero instead:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.shortcuts import render

def customer_view(request):
    customers = Customers.objects.annotate(
        total_spent=Coalesce(Sum('transactions__tx_amount'), Value(0))
    )
    context = {'customers' : customers}
    return render(request, load_template, context)
```